# Two models, one STI and a Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance, validation

Let's say I have two tables -- Products and Orders.  For the sake of simplicity assume that only one product can be purchased at a time so there is no join table like order_items.  So the relationship is that Product has many orders, and Order belongs to product.  Therefore, product_id is a fk in the Order table.

The product table is STI -- with the subclasses being A, B, C.

When the user orders subclass Product C, two special validations must be checked on the Order model fields order_details and order_status.  These two fields can be nil for all other Product subclasses (ie A and B). In other words, no validation needs to run for these two fields when a user purchases A and B.

My question is:

How do I write validations (perhaps custom?) in the Order model so that the Order model knows to only run the validations for ITS two fields -- order_details and order_status -- when the fk_id to Product subclass C is being saved to the orders table?

Comment: Is there an alternative to using polymorphism here?

Comment: yeah... see my edits again :) It just dawned on my what you were really after. With future questions it might be better to include the actual model code. Would have helped me out from the onset (then again I was all over the place so it may have been just me :)

Comment: yea, don't think it's you! it was my original prob statement. thx for help working through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to add a `validate` method in the `Order` model to check for specifics:

```
  def validate
    if product and product.type_c?
      errors.add(:order_details, "can't be blank") if order_details.blank?
      # any other validations
    end
  end
```

Or something along those lines. Just check for the type in `validate` and add the appropriate errors. I just made up the `type_c?` function. Just check the type however your `Product` model is defined.

Comment: Tony, will this still work if order_details and order_status fields are in the Order model?